# Use SWIG to wrap OpenCV's C++ API in GO

Tags: c++, opencv, go, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to wrap OpenCV's C++ API. For now, I have system-wise OpenCV installed. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to wrap "system-wise" library without putting them into the same directory of my SWIG files? For example, my opencv's header files are in `/usr/local/opt/opencv/opencv2/opencv.hpp`. Can I use `%include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` in SWIG?
2. How should I start with this work? Should I wrap the CONSTANTs first?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can %include any header file you like.  It doesn't have to be in the same directory.

I would start by thinking about the API you want to present to Go programs.  A good Go API is often different from a good C API.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!!! I've been looking for answers for so long! Could you provide a very simple example how I can use %include to wrap the cv core or some other modules? I've tried %include but get "xxx.hpp" not found ...